# Keyboard hides my half of edit-text and button below it even in scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview, soft-keyboard

I am having trouble with  keyboard covers my edit-text and half of button even in scroll view.

here's my layout , Please tell me how should i resolve this problem. Their are many questions on this topic but none of them s working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_layout_bg"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:singleLine="true"

                        android:textColor="@color/textcolor3"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/about_libraries_card_dark" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/md_grey_700" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/client_icon" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg"
                    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Register"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use only `adjustPan`. `adjustPan|adjustResize` together doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest for your activity specify

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

According to [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) this will have your desired effect

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

Comment: What is the fillViewport for? Did you try removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

You can also refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more clarification.

Comment: Did you try removing the scrollview and then use this setting? Do you need the scroll?